# Django - how to extend the session class?

Tags: python, django, datetime, session

In short, I want to store `datetime.datetime` values inside the session, but not to write in many places `datetime.strftime` or `datetime.strptime`

I use the default JSON serializer for the session, and I've read why I should not switch to `Pickle`.

So I thought I could implement it by extending the session class. So I would write in my views:

```
request.session.setDatetime('somekey', datetime_value)
```

and

```
request.session.getDatetime('somekey')
```

These will deal with converting the datetime from and to strings.

Is there a simple way to extend the session class without messing up too much of django internals?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why you are looking for extending session class. Once, I used the requests 'session' attribute as follows:

If you want to set session variable:
simply:

```
       request.session['myvar'] = 'testdata'
```

And to access that session variable:

```
       if 'myvar' in request.session:
           myvar = request.session['myvar']
```

Comment: datetime.datetime is not JSON serializable, you cannot store it in the session. That's why I have to convert from and to date strings

Comment: I don't think there is better way than simply converting the datetime object to string : ```json.dump(your_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))```

Comment: That's what currently do (just without the json.dumps, which is reluctant here). But I hoped to hide this logic in one place, rather then have strftime and strptime spread in many of my views.